# Electron - Unsupported Browser for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the below error when trying to retrieve a token in firebase:

```
code: "messaging/unsupported-browser"
message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."
stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
```

Is there a way to resolve this? I wanted to be able to create a messaging system between my android devices and this application. Somewhat like the slack application.

Here is a code snippet:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-app.js');  
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');  

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "myapikey",
    authDomain: "myauthdomain",
    databaseURL: "databaseurl",
    projectId: "projectid",
    storageBucket: "storagebucket",
    messagingSenderId: "senderID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});

messaging.getToken()
.then(function(currentToken) {
  if (currentToken) 
    console.log(currentToken);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);  
});
```

Comment: is there no update for this?

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move on to a framework called Node WebKit, which supports firebase messaging. Take a look into that. It is pretty simple and extremely similar to electron. Unfortunately, electron simply does not support firebase messaging. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, it really helped! I'mg going to add a question on Stackoverflow, may be some one solved that.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this lib [electron-push-receiver](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver).
Check it's docs, it worked great.(you might need to extract some code in case you are using Typescript)

IMPORTANT: add this line to the electron file: [check this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-336757899)

```
 webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: false,
  preload: __dirname + "/preload.js"  <----- here
}
```

and `preload.js`

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

then inside the app, replace the firebase messaging config by:

```
let { ipcRenderer } = window;
import {
 START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE,
 NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_STARTED,
 NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ERROR,
 NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED,
 TOKEN_UPDATED
} from "../constants/electron-push";


ipcRenderer.on(TOKEN_UPDATED, (_, token) => {
  setTokenSentToServer(false);
  sendTokenToServer(token);
});

ipcRenderer.on(NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED, (_, notification) => {
  console.log("NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED", notification);
  let { data } = notification;
  // here you get your data
});
// Listen for service successfully started
ipcRenderer.on(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_STARTED, (_, token) => {
  console.log("NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_STARTED", token);
  setTokenSentToServer(false);
  sendTokenToServer(token);
});
// Handle notification errors
ipcRenderer.on(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ERROR, (_, error) => {
  console.log("NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ERROR", error);
});
ipcRenderer.send(START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, senderId);
```

Comment: @FoxDonut yes it subscribe to firebase, only the code on the client side is changed a little, I even kept the same code, ```setTokenSentToServer``` and ```sendTokenToServer```...